# Why does Visual Studio not consider Obsolete("message") to be a warning?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, deprecation-warning

I've noticed a variation in how Visual Studio handles the use of code marked with the `ObsoleteAttribute`.

Assume some code calls a method that is marked with this attribute.

If the attribute was applied like this:

```
[Obsolete]
void Foo() { ... }
```

then Visual Studio will highlight any uses of `Foo` with a green underline, and they will show up in the error list pane as warnings.

But if you do it like this:

```
[Obsolete("message")]
void Foo() { ... }
```

then VS instead will almost ignore the uses of `Foo`. There is no warning. If you hover over it, only then would you see that it is "deprecated".

I was surprised by this difference... I haven't been able to find any references explaining why this is ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) which does not mention it).

This behavior is not helpful (at least in my situation) because people are actually overlooking these cases and using the deprecated code - despite the point of the message being to help inform them. I'd really like them to see the warning.

Is there a way to get VS to handle both of these cases the same way? i.e., treat them both as normal warnings?

I'm aware there is an overload for the attribute constructor that can force it to be treated as an *error*, but that's not what I'm asking about.

I'm using VS 2019, .NET472 project.

---

A comment asked if we have any `#pragma` lines to disable warnings. This is the single use of pragma in the code:

```
        #pragma warning disable CS0168
        catch (IOException ex)
        #pragma warning restore CS0168
```

this obviously does not use `Obsolete`, so I don't see how it could be related. And [CS0168](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0168) doesn't seem related to this either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the [`Warning level`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warn-compiler-option) setting of the `Build` configuration that drives this behaviour.

When the `ObsoleteAttribute` is being applied without a message, it results in a [`CS0612`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0612) warning,
which is `level 1`.

> Compiler warning (level 1) CS0612

Whereas the `ObsoleteAttribute` with a message, results in a [`CS0618`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0618) warning,
which is `level 2`.

> Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0618

Setting your warning level to `1` will ignore `CS0618`,
but restoring it to `4`, being the default, will show both as warnings.

---

[image]

---

```
[Obsolete] // CS0612
public static void DoSomething() { } 

[Obsolete("obsolete with custom message")] // CS0618
public static void DoSomethingElse() { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```